# php ajax contact form

Tags: php, html, ajax, contact-form

Im building a contact form using php and ajax with following code:

HTML:

```
<head>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>      
</head>
<body>
<form id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="php/mailer.php">    
   <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
   <input type="text" id="email" name="email" required>
   <textarea id="message" name="message" required></textarea>    
   <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<div id="form-messages">
</div>
</body>
```

AJAX:

```
$(function() {
    var form = $('#ajax-contact');

    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

});
$(form).submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

});
var formData = $(form).serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(form).attr('action'),
    data: formData
}).done(function(response) {
    $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
    $(formMessages).addClass('success');

    $(formMessages).text(response);

    $('#name').val('');
    $('#email').val('');
    $('#message').val('');
}).fail(function(data) {
    $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
    $(formMessages).addClass('error');

    if (data.responseText !== '') {
        $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
    } else {
        $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
    }
});
```

MAILER:

```
<?php

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
                $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

        if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }

        $recipient = "mailreceiver@example.com";

        $subject = "New contact from $name";

        $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

        $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
        } else {
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }

    } else {
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    }

?>
```

In Ajax on action I load the php mailer file to send the mail to my current mail address BUT I want to do this in the background the page shouldn't be loaded since I'm using ajax... I want to stay on the html page of the form without redirecting to that php page for sending that mail and just display succes or failure in the div:form-messages.

What am I missing here?

Comment: put the ajax call in the form submit function.

Comment: Tried and nothing, still redirected

Comment: try adding return false; before event.preventDefault();

Comment: Why @wayzz? The `preventDefault()` should be all that is needed.

Comment: Try a button type instead of an input.

Comment: Also make sure you've got `<!DOCTYPE html>`, it's not shown in your posted code along with all proper closing tags `</body>` and `</html>`.

Comment: Meaning, change `<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Send">` to `<button class="submit" type="submit">Send</button>`

Comment: Got tags in my file just not in example above and changing to button type didn't help

Comment: do you have the jquery functions in a $(dom).ready() function?

Comment: which functions do you mean? got the ajax call on the button submit which triggers the php file

Comment: put your javascript in the function $(dom).ready(function(){..code..}); and try it out.

Comment: Nothing still redirected...

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

Bind your input submit button with class "submit" to submit the form using ajax.
And you can reset the form using $(form)[0].reset(); insead of clear input values

```
$('.submit').click(function() { //<-- changed/new
    var form = $('#ajax-contact');
    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');
    var formData = $(form).serialize();

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
    }).done(function(response) {
            $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
            $(formMessages).addClass('success');

            $(formMessages).text(response);

            $(form)[0].reset(); //<-- changed/new

    }).fail(function(data) {
            $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
            $(formMessages).addClass('error');

            if (data.responseText !== '') {
                $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
            } else {
                $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try with this"? Please be clear about what you've done for the OP and for future visitors to SO. In addition, you have not prevented redirection.

Comment: remove the "method" from <form> and try again as well remove type="submit" from your input

Comment: last try: remove action from <form> and modify "url: $(form).attr('action')" to "url: php/mailer.php". If still dosn't work try to add a eventHandler function into the bind click.

Comment: removing action from form and changing the to: url: php/mailer.php, stops redirecting but nothing happens now

Comment: add an alert(true) to your bind click code. If when you click into the input, the alert appears it means that you have some error in your AJAX call. so as well lock the browser console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

try with something like this:

```
$('.submit').click(function(event) {
    //use this to dont submit the form
    event.preventDefault(); 
    //your ajax stuff
    $.ajax....
    //if you dont want to use the preventDefault function just
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't prevent redirecting

Comment: comment `$(form).submit(function(event) {` function

Comment: Don't quite understand your comment?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `action="php/mailer"` and do something like the following

```
function sendEmail(message){
    var data = new XMLHttpRequest();
    data.open("POST","php/mailer.php");

    data.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(data.readyState === 4 && data.status === 200){
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "Email sent";
        }
    }
    data.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    data.send("message=" + message);
}
```

the you can call the function in the submit button.